# iOS 13 SwiftUI: app crashes upon launch on real device

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode11, ios13

After the releases of SwiftUI and Apple’s new betas (macOS 10.15, iOS 13, and Xcode 11), I began developing an application built on the new technologies.

Development had gone smoothly, considering all the software and systems involved were in beta. However, upon trying to run the SwiftUI-based app on a real device (iPhone 8 Plus, running iOS 13 beta 2), the application refused to start, instead crashing on launch with a simple `(lldb)` in the Xcode debugger. The app had worked properly in the simulator, and Xcode has provided no helpful messages as to why the app will not run on a real device.

**tl;dr** after running successfully in the iOS 13 simulator, SwiftUI app crashes on launch on real iOS 13 device.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If this is Xcode 11 beta 2 (released yesterday), you should immediately file a bug report with Apple and send along your project.

Comment: I’m running Xcode 11 beta 1, though I did file a bug report. Now that you mentioned the new release, I’ll look into upgrading, and see if the issue persists!

Comment: Cool, thanks on both counts. If it's not fixed, I would advise appending a note to your existing bug report saying so (if that's possible under the new bug reporter).

Comment: The issue was resolved in Xcode beta 2. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt)!

It turns out the issue was just a bug in Xcode 11 beta 1, preventing SwiftUI-based apps from being testing on real devices. Upgrading to Xcode 11 beta 2 resolved the issue.